# Error: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x

Hola soy estudiante estoy aprendiendo phyton, vengo de C.
Tengo una pregunta super estúpida que lo logro solucionar
Necesito ingresar un vector de 10 numeros enteros y ver si estan en orden creciente o no.

Mi código es el siguiente

```
def funcion_orden (b):
   
   for i in range(0,10):
        if(i>1):
            if(b[i]>b[i-1]):
             c=1
            else: 
                c = 0
                return c

 
    

a=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for i in range(0,10):
    a =  int(input( "Ingresa el dato numero {}: ".format(i+1) ))

orden=funcion_orden(a)
```

y me da el siguiente error
File "C:\Users\Sebastián.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 19, in 
orden=funcion_orden(a)

File "C:\Users\Sebastián.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 5, in funcion_orden
if(b[i]>b[i-1]):

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Llamas a la función `funcion_orden` pasando como parámetro el valor recibido por teclado (convertido a `int`).

El valor lo recibes en la variable `a`, que hasta ese momento contenía una lista de valores. Reemplazaste una lista con una variable.

Luego, dentro de esa función, tomas el valor entero recibido en `b` y ejecutas:

```
if(b[i] > b[i-1]):
```

Pero `b` es entero. Probablemente le querías pasar el arreglo `a`, pero este dejó de existir cuando le asignaste la entrada.

#### Solución

Primero, no tiene sentido fijar las dimensiones de la lista. Podemos ser flexibles, aceptando cualquier lista que el usuario ingrese (terminada con cero u otro valor sentinela).

**Verificar orden**

La función recibe una lista de valores (largo arbitrario) y retorna `True` si están en orden ascendente, o `False` en caso contrario.

```
def funcion_orden(b):
    for i in range(1, len(b)):
        if b[i] < b[i - 1]:
            return False
    return True
```

La función compara el elemento actual con el elemento anterior de la lista, por lo que el ciclo debe comenzar desde 1, no desde cero.

Como la condición es que cada elemento sea mayor o igual al anterior, tan pronto la condición se rompe, retornamos con el valor `False`, para señalar que la lista no está ordenada.

Si llegamos al final de la lista sin problemas, entonces la lista está ordenada y retornamos con `True`

**Ingreso**

```
a = []
while True:
    valor = int(input("Ingresa el dato numero {}: ".format(len(a) + 1)))
    if valor:
        a.append(valor)
    else:
        break
```

Para el ingreso de valores parto con una lista vacía, añadiendo valores vía `append`. Cuando se recibe un cero, se termina el ingreso.

**Comprobación**

```
if funcion_orden(a):
    print("Datos en orden")
else:
    print("Datos desordenados")
```

Finalmente, se llama a la función y se imprime el mensaje correspondiente al valor retornado.

Demo

```
def funcion_orden(b):
    for i in range(1, len(b)):
        if b[i] < b[i - 1]:
            return False
    return True

a = []
while True:
    valor = int(input("Ingresa el dato numero {}: ".format(len(a) + 1)))
    if valor:
        a.append(valor)
    else:
        break

if funcion_orden(a):
    print("Datos en orden")
else:
    print("Datos desordenados")
```

produce:

```
Ingresa el dato numero 1: 1
Ingresa el dato numero 2: 2
Ingresa el dato numero 3: 3
Ingresa el dato numero 4: 0
Datos en orden

Process finished with exit code 0
```

y

```
Ingresa el dato numero 1: 3
Ingresa el dato numero 2: 2
Ingresa el dato numero 3: 1
Ingresa el dato numero 4: 0
Datos desordenados

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Lo que quiero lograr es ingresar un vector de 10  números enteros y ver si están ordenados de menor a mayor

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega ese comentario para que todos lo vean.

Comment: @SebastiánLobosCornejo. Edite mi respuesta para incluir la solución

Comment: Genial, Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En python no tienes que inicializar los valores de las listas. Estas se expanden o reducen dinámicamente.

Python es un lenguaje de tipado dinámico, por ende las variables pueden sobreescribir el tipo en la asignación.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> type(a)
<class 'list'>
>>> a = 2
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
```

Como sobreescribiste la lista con un entero, si le tratas de sacar un índice a este valor, aparece el error que dices:

```
>>> a[1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Modificando un poco la lógica de la función y el codigo principal:

```
def funcion_orden (b):
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if (i > 0) and (b[i] < b[i-1]):
            return False
    return True

a=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    var = int(input("Ingresa el dato numero {}: ".format(i+1) ))
    a.append(var)

orden=funcion_orden(a)
print(orden)
```

Puedes cambiar `True` y `False` por `1` y `0`, aunque es usual devolver el dato booleano.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!